# Does $E(Z\vert X) = 0$ mean $Z$ does not include a non-zero constant?

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let $Z, X$ be random vectors. If $E(Z\vert X) = 0$ then is it impossible for $Z$ to include a *non-zero* constant? That is, it is impossible for $Z$ to look like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & z_{12} & z_{13} &... & z_{1t}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
instead of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
z_{11} & z_{12} & z_{13} &... & z_{1t}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
letting $Z, X$ be $(1 \times t)$, and where $z_it$ are random variables.

I believe the answer is trivially yes, because if $Z$ contains a non-zero constant -- say $1$ -- then that constant must show up in the expectation, hence ruling out the zero vector?

I also feel like I'm overlooking something or that I may be understanding expectations/random vectors improperly..

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean nonzero constant?

Comment: @ArtemMavrin Yes, Nonzero constant. Thank you.

Comment: You are not missing anything.  It is exactly that trivial.  If one element of the random vector never varies, and the expectation of that element is zero, then that constant element cannot be non-zero.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let $\mathbf o=(0,0,...)$ be the constant zero vector.

Then let $\mathbf Z$ contain at least one non-zero constant member, for example: $\mathbf Z=(1,Z_2,...)$.   It is then clearly impossible for $\mathsf E(\mathbf Z\mid \mathbf X) = \mathbf o$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant non-zero constant. Otherwise your answer would be acceptable.